# xsl:result-document instruction throws error when invoking stylesheet with Calabash

Tags: xslt, xproc

I have an XSL stylesheet that looks like this:

```
<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="collection($doc-collection)//dr:description" group-by="format-date(dr:date, '[Mn]-[Y]')">
    <xsl:result-document href="{current-grouping-key()}.html" method="html" indent="yes">
      <xsl:call-template name="page">
        <xsl:with-param name="desc" select="current-group()"/>
      </xsl:call-template>  
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

(Variables and other templates omitted for brevity.)

When I invoke this using Saxon, everything runs fine and I end up with x documents created through xsl:result-document.

When it is run as part of an XProc pipeline with Calabash as follows:

```
<p:xslt name="transformation" template-name="xsl:initial-template">
  <p:input port="stylesheet">
    <p:document href="../xslt/main.xsl"/>
  </p:input>
  <p:input port="source">
    <p:empty/>
  </p:input>
  <p:with-param name="doc-collection" select="resolve-uri($source)"/>
</p:xslt>
```

I get a run-time error during the transformation: `Cannot execute xsl:result-document while evaluating xsl:variable`. I tried stripping down the code to a bare minimum, but I cannot prevent the error from occuring when calling `xsl:result-document`.

I don't know what variable it is referring to, I can only assume it is created somewhere inside the pipeline?

Working with Saxon EE 9.9.1.5 and Calabash 1.1.30-99 inside Oxygen XML Developer.

Comment: Sounds odd although you haven't shown us how where/how you set `$source` in the XProc. Anyway, you can raise it with the oXygen support if it only happens inside oXygen or as an issue with Calabash on GitHub if it is Calabash related.

Comment: It seems I was misguided - the error was thrown by the XSpec test runner that preceded the transformation step in the pipeline (and tried to wrap the result in a variable!).