# What is the cause of [ERROR] Cannot execute xsl:result-document while evaluating xsl:variable; (using XSpec)

Tags: xslt, saxon, xspec

We installed and ran XSpec and configured it to point to our stylesheet resulting in an error:

> [ERROR] Cannot execute xsl:result-document while evaluating
> xsl:variable; SystemID: file:/Users/a/xspec/ce.xslt; Line#: 76;
> Column#: 114 net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Cannot execute
> xsl:result-document while evaluating xsl:variable

A similar error has been found by user:wasmachien and a question was raised on
[xsl:result-document instruction throws error when invoking stylesheet with Calabash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62961923/xslresult-document-instruction-throws-error-when-invoking-stylesheet-with-calab)

The solution to the error was not given, but it pointed to:

> the error was thrown by the XSpec test runner that preceded the
> transformation step in the pipeline (and tried to wrap the result in a
> variable!)

We would be helped if we know how to avoid that behaviour.

Comment: Is `ce.xslt` your code or XSpec code? Can you show the relevant lines, i.e. at least the template or function containing line 76?

Answer (score 1):

XSLT is a functional language, so evaluating a variable isn't supposed to have side-effects like creating an output file. The error message means that you're trying to cause such a side-effect. This would be bad news because side-effects prevent many optimisations, so the XSLT spec bans this.

Of course I can see why this is a nuisance. If you have some code that's doing a transformation then you want to be able to capture the result of the code in a variable. But the whole point is that if the code has side-effects, then you can't encapsulate it in this way: in effect, the code is actually producing multiple results.

I don't know whether anyone has worked on making XSpec able to run XSLT transformations using `fn:transform()`. That would be an ideal solution, because `fn:transform` allows the target transformation to produce multiple results using `xsl:result-document`, and it captures all the result documents using a map.

Comment: The latest XSpec has an experimental feature where it invokes the tested stylesheet using `fn:transform()`. Unfortunately this feature doesn't seem to work when the tested stylesheet uses `xsl:result-document`. Saxon is terminated, saying `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The result sequence has not yet been closed`. Is `xsl:result-document` not allowed to be used when its stylesheet is invoked using `fn:transform()` within `xsl:result-document`? (The new feature calls `fn:transform()` still within `xsl:result-document`.)

Comment: In principle Saxon does allow a stylesheet invoked using fn:transform() to use xsl:result-document, though you may have to choose the right options in fn:transform() for how the result documents are delivered. Try to construct a simple example that demonstrates a failure and raise it as a separate question.

Comment: Actually, the IllegalStateException could be a bug, so it would certainly be good to see the conditions that trigger it.

Comment: I'll open an issue after narrowing down a repro.

Comment: Thanks: for reference, https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4835

Comment: Fix verified on Saxon-HE 10.5.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the problem here is that XSpec attempts to capture the output of the transformation in a variable so that it can compare the results against what's expected. But you can't have an `xsl:result-document` in a variable for the reasons Mike describes.

Without an XSpec rewrite to avoid this, you have to twist your stylesheet so that it doesn't attempt to use `xsl:result-document` within the templates that are being tested (or when they're being tested).

There's some magic along these lines in the tests for https://github.com/docbook/xslTNG/

Answer (score 0):

As answered by the others, that is an inherent limitation of the current XSpec implementation. You have to tweak your stylesheet to make it testable.

"High-Level File Structure to Enable Substitution" and "Case 1: Creating Result Documents" in galtm's [paper](https://www.balisage.net/Proceedings/vol25/html/Galtman01/BalisageVol25-Galtman01.html#d9267e189) might give you some hint. It's based on Saxon-JS, but many of its strategies are applicable to Saxon Java.